# Circular/carousel like listview "setSelection"

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview , and I have given a `circular/carousel` effect to the list by giving `setSelection(SomeHighValueNumber)`. And now I need the actual functionality of the `setSelection(position)` to move to a particular position. Since I have already used `setSelection` to get circular effect, how can I achieve this?

For Instance,

In adapter class, I have done the following

```
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position%mListAdapterCount);
        }
```

Then,

```
LvR = (TwoWayView)mainLayoutR.findViewById(R.id.listViewR);
LvR.setAdapter(applicationsAdapter);
LvR.setSelection(500);
```

Now say I want to move to 6th position in listview LvR. I can't use setSelection again, since it removes the carousel effect from my listview LvR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution myself. Here you go

For Instance,

int selection = 500;

LvR.setSelection(selection);

And if you want to move to Xth position in listview LvR. Use this

LvR.setSelection(selection+X);